# On FreeBSD, or other BSDs, what directory is commonly used for data folder storing the content of a database such as Postgres

Tags: freebsd, directory, directory-structure, postgresql, bsd

I am wondering if there is a convention on where to store the data folder containing all the files for the tables and rows of a relational database system such as Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On OpenBSD, the (OpenBSD) `postgresql-server` package will be preconfigured to use `/var/postgresql/data` for its databases.  It also adds a `_postgresql` service user with `/var/postgresql` as its home directory.

Storing databases under `/var` makes sense as they generally contain variable data.  If your `/var` partition is not big enough, you may consider changing this to some other location where you have more space, or mounting a separate filesystem at `/var/postgresql`.  Unfortunately, I'm not a FreeBSD user and can not tell you how to do that in the most convenient way for PostgreSQL on FreeBSD.

On OpenBSD, changing the location of the data directory would involve changing a `datadir` variable in the `rc` script `/etc/rc.d/postgresql` (this particular variable does not seem to be configurable through the native `rcctl` utility for whatever reason).

---

From a comment by JdeBP: For FreeBSD, the default location for the databases is `/var/db/postgres/data10` (presumably this is for PostgreSQL 10).  This is configurable by changing/setting the value of the `postgresql_data` variable in `/etc/rc.conf`.

Comment: Mounting a filesystem with more space on `/var/postgres` is also an option. Also, relevant man page for filesystem hierarchy: https://man.openbsd.org/hier

Comment: `/var/db/postgres/data10` and `postgresql_data` in `/etc/rc.conf`

Comment: @JdeBP Check my addition. Correct?

Comment: [I believe so](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/databases/postgresql10-server/files/postgresql.in?view=markup#l9).