# How did /var/lib get its name?

Tags: linux, history

The [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s08.html) says that `/var/lib` "holds state information pertaining to an application or the system."

FreeBSD doesn't mention `/var/lib` in [`hier(7)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hier&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html). The closest thing I can find is `/var/db` ("miscellaneous automatically generated system-specific database files"), which seems like a more descriptive name.

Where did `/var/lib` come from, and how did it get its name? I don't see the connection between `/var/lib` and libraries. Or does `lib` stand for something else in this case? Is it Linux-specific, or is this a System V vs BSD difference?

Comment: Related discussion about where BSDs store database and state files (interestingly, OpenBSD doesn't use `/var/db` for this): https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/484137/206286

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [LHFS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05.html#purpose31) also says about `/var` as a whole:

> `/var` is specified here in order to make it possible to mount `/usr` read-only. Everything that once went into `/usr` that is written to during system operation (as opposed to installation and software maintenance) must be in `/var`.

And this is the link to the past for `/var/lib`: "once" there were files in `/usr/lib` that were written - and those now should be put into the `/var` structure - to `/var/lib` (probably to find them easier if you once were used to look for them in `/usr/lib`? )

BTW, `/var/db` from BSD is also mentioned in the [LHFS](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s08.html#purpose41), those files are put into `/var/lib/misc` in the LHFS.